# How to undo a system property setting in Websphere when without starting it

Tags: configuration, websphere-6.1

I'm forced to use a Websphere Application Server 6.1.

I configured some system properties using the admin console, but now the application server doesn't start at all. Which also means I can't access the admin console to remove the system properties which probably cause the problem.

How can I remove the system properties without actually starting the application server?

In case it is of any relevance, the system properties are:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If finally found the file where this kind of configuration is stored. On my machine it is

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\config\cells\ddea1846Node01Cell\nodes\ddea1846Node01\servers\server1\server.xml
```

In that file one can find the setting in question and remove it.